# Funcall inside Cons Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I just began to play with Lisp and I'm trying to use funcall inside cons.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
(cons  '(1 2 3) '(1 (funcall #'rest '(a b)) ))
```

The result should be:

```
((1 2 3) 1 (b))
```

I know this works:

```
(cons  '(1 2 3) (funcall #'rest '(a b)))
```

And I tried this already and it didn't work

```
(cons  '(1 2 3) `,'(1 (funcall #'rest '(a b)) ))
(cons '(1 2 3) '(1 (apply 'rest '(a b))))
(cons '(1 2 3) '(1 `,(apply 'rest '(a b))))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(cons '(1 2 3) `(1 ,(funcall #'rest '(a b))))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you quote a list, everything is quoted inside the list, so there is no function call. You can achieve what you want like this:

```
[1]> (cons  '(1 2 3) (list 1 (funcall #'rest '(a b)) ))
((1 2 3) 1 (B))
[2]>
```

Comment: @candiani Sorry, I didn't copy-paste this properly from my clisp session last night, now it's correct.